# Python random sports schedule generator

Tags: python

I found the following

[Generating natural schedule for a sports league](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913616/generating-natural-schedule-for-a-sports-league)

That generates the same schedule each time you run it.. If I add a random.shuffle() in there it's still too predictable.

Below is my simple edit from that post with a random in place and I get odd results

```
import random

def round_robin(units, sets = None):
    """ Generates a schedule of "fair" pairings from a list of units """
    count = len(units)
    sets = sets or (count - 1)
    half = count / 2

    for turn in range(sets):
        left = units[:half]
        right = units[count - half - 1 + 1:][::-1]
        pairings = zip(left, right)
        if turn % 2 == 1:
            pairings = [(y, x) for (x, y) in pairings]
        units.insert(1, units.pop())

        yield pairings


teams = range(5)
random.shuffle(teams)
schedule = list(round_robin(teams, sets = len(teams) * 2 - 2))

for week in schedule:
    for game in week:
        if 0 in game:
            print game
```

sometimes it seems teams won't even play each other.. see the results

```
(0, 4)
(4, 0)
(0, 2)
(0, 4)
(4, 0)
(0, 2)
```

My question is.. how can I do a random schedule generator in python or fix what I have already.

Pretty much I need to take 4 teams and come out with 3 weeks of play where they play each other once. Or like 5 teams where there are 5 weeks of play and they all play each other once but one team is left out per week

Comment: I'm not sure what's the question.

Comment: sorry... question added at the bottom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that each team needs to play with other team. Is it not? Then does not this question boil down to simple permutation and then shuffling the result?

```
import itertools
import random
set_size = 2
schedule = set()
teams = range(5)
for comb in itertools.product(teams, repeat=set_size):
    comb = sorted(list(comb))
    if len(set(comb)) == set_size:
        schedule.add(tuple(comb))

schedule = list(schedule)
random.shuffle(schedule)
print schedule
```

Comment: This is NOT the correct answer. You might still end up with the same team playing twice or more in a row. But each team can play only once per play event (week as per OP example). So the schedule must produce a list of events where in every week, every team plays at most once.